# Laravel returns uploaded file instead of it path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am uploading a file and saving it in local storage. These files are stored in the database related to a particular user. When i return the last saved user. I get other details in response properly. But instead of the file path. I get the file as response

```
 $file = $request->file('resume');
 $profile_id = $request['profile_id'];
 $original_name = $_FILES['resume']['name'];                
 $resume_new_name = str_random(). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $new_file = $request->file('resume')->move('resources/assets/resumes',$resume_new_name);
 $candidate_info['resume'] = $new_file;
 $candidate = new candidate();
    if (empty($candidate_info['name'])) {
           $candidate_info['name'] = $candidate_info['email'];
     }
        $candidate->name = $candidate_info['name'];
        $candidate->phone = $candidate_info['phone'];
        $candidate->email = $candidate_info['email'];
        $candidate->resume = $candidate_info['resume'];
        $candidate->client_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $candidate->status = "new";
        $candidate->profile_id = $profile_id;
        $candidate->save();
        return response()->json(['msg' => $candidate]);
```

In database column 'resume' it stores the path. But in json response it sends the whole file instead of the path. how do i send the path instead of sending the whole file

Answer (score 0):

Just return the value of that one column:

```
return response()->json(['msg' => $candidate->resume]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **move** use **store**

```
$new_file = $request->file('resume')->store('resources/assets/resumes',$resume_new_name);
```